# How to connect to github with AWS CDK using codebuild?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-codebuild

I have the following github source:

```js
const gitHubSource = cb.Source.gitHub({
    owner: 'me',
    repo: 'repo',
    webhook: true,
    OAuthToken: '',
    webhookFilters: [
      cb.FilterGroup
        .inEventOf(cb.EventAction.PUSH, cb.EventAction.PULL_REQUEST_MERGED)
        .andBranchIs('dev')
    ],
});
```

Here is the codebuild project:

```js
new cb.Project(this, 'MyProject', {
    environmentVariables: {
      "BUCKET_NAME": { value: bucket.bucketName },
      "CF_DIST_ID": { value: distribution.distributionId }
    },
    source: gitHubSource
});
```

It fails because its unable to find the oauth token:

```sh
    10:49:45 | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::CodeBuild::Project                         | 
    MyProject39F7B0AE
    Failed to call CreateWebhook, reason: Could not find access token for server type 
    github (Service: AWSCo
    deBuild; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ResourceNotFoundException; Request ID: 
    99d1fd6d-bd2c-49b8-bbed-82
    06636055b5; Proxy: null)
```

Reading the docs I dont find a way to pass oauth tokens to cb.Source.gitHub neither to cb.Project (cb stands for codebuild btw).

I already have a github connection in my aws account:
[image]

Is there some way to use this existing connection? if not, how can I pass the oauthtoken to  codebuild or github source?

Answer (score 3):

Codebuild uses your [github personal access token](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/access-tokens.html) to access github.  You give Codebuild your token *one time only*. It's not added to each project:

> [CDK Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codebuild-readme.html#credentials): the credentials are global to a given account in a given region - they are not defined per CodeBuild project. CodeBuild only allows storing a single credential of a given type (GitHub, GitHub Enterprise or BitBucket) in a given account in a given region - any attempt to save more than one will result in an error. You can use the list-source-credentials AWS CLI operation to inspect what credentials are stored in your account.

You can use the CDK for the one-time credential adding step:

```js
new codebuild.GitHubSourceCredentials(this, 'CodeBuildGitHubCreds', {
  accessToken: SecretValue.secretsManager('my-token'),
});
```

Comment: but how can I tell codebuild to use  this variables? it doesnt has a oautToken field

Comment: It's global to your account and you can only have one. It will use what you set.

Comment: Credentials _"are not defined per CodeBuild project"_ but rather as a one-time step.  Codebuild gave you the `Could not find access token for server type github` error because you didn't do this.  `new codebuild.GitHubSourceCredentials` is the CDK method to perform the one-time step.  Codebuild does the rest.

Comment: You can put your token in parameters store or secret manager. Your codebuild project needs a buildspec.yml, right? then you declare under env ( parameter-store or secrets-manager).

Comment: @FranxiHidro  The token is global, not the project's concern. It does not go into the project's `buildspec`.

Comment: @redigaffi I expanded the answer and added a comment.   kichik's comment is helpful.

Comment: Note that "You give CodeBuild your token one time only" is incorrect. GitHub limits token lifetime to a maximum of 12 months. Meaning you will have to undertake a manual process every year, or your build project will fail.  CodePipeline can use a "connection" that doesn't expire this way, but I don't think CodeBuild supports connections yet.

@fedonev

Comment: Sadly, `SecretValue.ssmSecure` doesn't work, and you have to pay the extra $0.40/mo for `SecretValue.secretsManager()`